# execute php document with another php document

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I want to execute a php doc through another php doc using the exec() function. The code I have works on my local setup but for some reason it fails on my remote setup.

If I type the command directly in the command line `php /home/user/domains/sitename/public_html/testing/doc1.php` or `php /home/user/domains/sitename/public_html/testing/doc2.php testing` as any user, it executes fine and I see one new database entry. If I run doc1 directly from the browser it fails.

Folders are permission 755 and php docs are 644.

Anyone have any ideas?

**Doc 1**

```
exec('php /home/user/domains/sitename/public_html/testing/exec_test.php testing');
```

**Doc 2 in above directory**

```
include("/home/user/domains/sitename/public_html/connection_dir/connection.php");
$db = new PDOConnectionFactory();
$conn = $db->getConnection();

//prepare for utf8 characters
$sql = 'SET NAMES utf8';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt->execute();

$sql = 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt->execute();
//**************************

$test=$argv[1];

 $sql = 'INSERT INTO video
(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)';
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt3->execute(array('','',$test,'','untitled','1'));
```

Comment: have you tried putting the full path to php?  could be the 'www' user doesn't have the same path as the users you have tested with

Comment: Use the `&$output` parameter of `exec()` to see what you get back. At a guess, I'd say you need to provide the full path to the `php` binary, eg `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: You boys were right. Boy I feel silly lol. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `php` executable is probably not in `$PATH`. Specify the full path to your php interpreter, i.e. `/usr/bin/php`.

Also if you don't have a good reason to use exec, just `include` the file.

Comment: I did not include all my code. You are right in specifying the whole path and it worked. The only reason I am using exec is because the php doc is executed after an ffmpeg command which requires exec. It is conditional on &&. Thanks a lot cweiske. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `passthru()` ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php ) to execute command so you will be able to see what errors are thrown